# upgrade 14.04 with errors and shows red sign on top

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, error-handling

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 but it shows a red symbol on the top and gives error message in function update

```
E:unknown error:<type exceptions.type error> upgrade manager or any other file is not present
```

Comment: Some questions for you that will help us in answering: From which Ubuntu version did you upgrade to 14.04? How did you upgrade (from the console or using the GUI)? Did you get any error messages while upgrading? Did you reboot after the upgrade?

Comment: from 12.04     i upgraded from console  yes i got error while upgrading  i infact got a blank screen yes i rebooted

Comment: What happens if you run `do-release-upgrade`? Does it tell you there is no new version, or does it continue the upgrade process?

Comment: it says no release found

Answer (score -2):

**This can damage stuff. Do not run these commands unless you know what you're doing!**

Hi Please try these options

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: This can damage stuff. **Do not run these commands unless you know what you're doing!**